# How to kill a single apache connection without a server restart?

Tags: apache

Using the apache status module, you can see what connections are currently connected through apache. Without restarting the apache service, I would like to kill some of those connections.

A line from the status looks something like:

```
Srv PID ... 
2-0 3326 ...
```

What is the best way to kill just one of these connections?

Can one, with impunity, in a shell just kill the PID shown from apache status?

Will this harm apache in some way if some of its child processes are manually killed?

Will it still be able to respawn new processes correctly?

Any strange side effects one should be aware of?

Comment: I'm looking to drop some subset of the connections though. A graceful restart, as you say, won't drop any connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having done this with impunity for a while, it appears that killing the process by using the PID given from apache status indeed is an effective and safe (at least as far as I can tell) way to kill an individual connection and keep the server alive.